# When adding $("#something").draggable to an element and the parent gets removed, does .draggable get garbaged collected?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, garbage-collection

If I add `$("#someid").draggable()` to any element or list of elements, and remove the parent element (or replace the html of the parent element with `.html()`), would I need to do anything to garbage collect the `.draggable` that I created?  I do not want that `draggable` to stay in memory and slow down the application.

Comment: As long as you use jQuery APIs to mess with the DOM, you should be OK.

Comment: If you are worried, destroy it before you do the remove.